# The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries: FireBaseCoreInternal and FireBaseStorage

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, podfile

I'm having this problem, and I've already tried the basic solutions of use_frameworks! and use_modular_headers!, neither of which work for me, as they produce the same error:

The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

The Swift pod `FirebaseStorage` depends upon `FirebaseAppCheckInterop`, `FirebaseAuthInterop`, `FirebaseCore`, `FirebaseCoreExtension`, and `GTMSessionFetcher`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

Here is the following podfile. I've tried doing a lot of things, and I really don't know how to fix this and make it work:

## Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

## platform :ios, '11.0'

## CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.

```
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
    'Debug' => :debug,
    'Profile' => :release,
    'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter',   'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
end

File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
end
raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    target 'RunnerTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    end
end
```